# rectification of direction field and coordinate system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, reduction-of-order-ode

Consider
$$
\dot x=0,\qquad \dot y =1 \qquad (\star)
$$

Rectify the induced direction field is to find a  diffeomorphism $(\tau,u,v) =\phi(t,x,y)$ such that $\frac{d u}{d \tau}=0=\frac{d v}{d\tau}$.

1. Why does $\phi$ modify $t$ in $\tau$? I can't find an example where we have $\tau\neq t$.

In the Polar coordinates (where $x$ is the radius and $y$ is the polar angle), this differential equation defines a direction field whose line through the point $(x,y)$ has orthogonal vector $(x,y)$.

In the Cartesian coordinates, this differential equation defines a direction field whose lines are vertical at every point.

Here take $\tau=t,u=x,v=v-t$ and we have $\dot u=0=\dot v$.

This rectified field is parallel to the t axis for both coordinate system.

So we see that $\phi$ (so the rectification) doesn't depend on the coordinate systems.

2. But we won't have the same result if $\tau \neq t$, in that case, the rectified direction field won't be the same with different coordinate systems ?
3. Why a vector field is not rectifiable near a periodic orbit ?